# Only Firefox displays HTML Code and not the page

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, simplehttpserver

I have this complicated problem that I can't find a answer to.

I have a Python HTTPServer running that serves webpages. These webpages are created at runtime with help of Beautiful Soup. Problem is that the Firefox shows HTML Code for the webpage and not the actual page? I really don't know know who is causing this problem -
- Python HTTPServer
- Beautiful Soup
- HTML Code

Any case, I have copied parts of the webpage HTML:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title>
   My title
  </title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="./123_ui.js">
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
  Hellos
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Just to help you, here are the things that I have already tried-
- I have made sure that Python HTTPServer is sending the MIME header as text/html
- Just copying and pasting the HTML Code will show you correct page as its static. I can tell from here that the problem is in HTTPServer side
- The Firebug shows that  is empty and "This element has no style rules. You can create a rule for it." is displayed

I just want to know if the  error is in Beautiful Soup or HTTPServer or HTML?

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 2):

Why are you adding this at the top of the document?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```

That will make the browser think the entire document is **XML** and *not* **XHTML**. Removing that line should make it render correctly. I assume Firefox is displaying a page with a bunch of elements which you can expand/collapse to see the content like it normally would for an XML document, even though the HTTP headers might say it's text/html.

Comment: There is no need of that you say. Fine, I removed it and its still the same. I am getting the same problem with or without the xml tag.

Comment: Do you have this online somewhere that we could look at it?

Comment: So guys,
I have finally solved this problem. The reason was because I wasn't sending MIME header (even though I thought I was) with content type "text/html"

In python HTTPServer, before writing anything to file you always do this:-

 self.send_response(301)
 self.send_header("Location", self.path + "/")
 self.end_headers()

 # Once you have called the above methods, you can send the HTML to Client
 self.wfile.write('ANY HTML CODE YOU WANT TO WRITE')

Comment: I am sorry.. but i don't have it online due to company policies... Any case, I have solved the problem.. thnks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

So guys,
I have finally solved this problem. The reason was because I wasn't sending MIME header (even though I thought I was) with content type "text/html"

In python HTTPServer, before writing anything to file you always do this:-

```
self.send_response(301)
self.send_header("Location", self.path + "/")
self.end_headers()
# Once you have called the above methods, you can send the HTML to Client                                                          
self.wfile.write('ANY HTML CODE YOU WANT TO WRITE')
```